# Sitecore fast way to check the mediaItem in the Media Library is an Image or a picture

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

For the item in Sitecore 'Media Library':

```
MediaItem mediaItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{E47591D0-48D2-4543-80E4-3836B02AA1A8}");
```

The above item is a picture "Tulips.jpg".

How can I check, from code behind, that the above item is actually a Picture/Image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have your `MediaItem` object, you can do this:

```cs
MediaItem mediaItem = ...

bool isPicture = mediaItem.MimeType.StartsWith("image/");
```

This works because [MIME types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) of images are formed like this: `image/...`. For example:

- image/bmp
- image/gif
- image/jpeg

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Dmytro Shevchenko suggestion is to use Sitecore's API to check the `Template` of the `MediaItem` containing the image opposed to doing a string comparison.

When an Image is uploaded to the `MediaLibrary` it is stored an `versioned` or `unversioned` template and either `Image` or `jpeg`.

So to check if the `mediaItem` is an image you can do the following;

```cs
public ID ImageUnversioned = new ID("{F1828A2C-7E5D-4BBD-98CA-320474871548}");
public ID JpegUnversioned = new ID("{DAF085E8-602E-43A6-8299-038FF171349F}");
public ID ImageVersioned = new ID("{C97BA923-8009-4858-BDD5-D8BE5FCCECF7}");
public ID JpegVersioned = new ID("{EB3FB96C-D56B-4AC9-97F8-F07B24BB9BF7}");

public bool IsImage(Item mediaItem)
{
    return mediaItem.TemplateID.Equals(ImageUnversioned)
           || mediaItem.TemplateID.Equals(JpegUnversioned)
           || mediaItem.TemplateID.Equals(ImageVersioned)
           || mediaItem.TemplateID.Equals(JpegVersioned);
}
```

Then simply pass in the `mediaItem` as below;

```cs
bool isImageOrPicture = IsImage(mediaItem);
```

## Update

[Dmytro Shevchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236660/) made a great point of recursively checking all base templates of the item, as the `Jpeg` Template descends from the `Image` template. Implementing as such:

```cs
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

...

public static bool IsImage(Item item)
{
    if (item.TemplateID == TemplateIDs.VersionedImage 
        || item.TemplateID == TemplateIDs.UnversionedImage)
    {
        return true;
    }

    foreach (TemplateItem baseTemplate in item.Template.BaseTemplates)
    {
        if (IsImage(baseTemplate))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach! By the way, the jpeg templates are descended from the image templates. Keeping in mind that in the future there may be other image-descended templates, I would suggest this (more universal) implementation: http://pastebin.com/tnREpgGb If you want, you can reuse this code for your answer.

Comment: I like that a lot! +1

Comment: Will you include this code in your answer? I think it would make sense to do that. Otherwise, I can include it in mine. By the way, this fixed code actually compiles and works :) http://pastebin.com/B31BpWSC

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore has a helper on the Sitecore Item class **IsMediaItem**

```
Sitecore.Context.Item.Paths.IsMediaItem
```

This code checks whether the item has a path containing “sitecore/Media library”

You could check the item before converting it to a media item.

Comment: I think Kami wants to find out whether the media item is an image. The thing is that it is possible to upload other types of media items, such as videos, PDFs and audio files.

Comment: Ah yes true, if that's the case then your answer would work. Mine only checks if its path contains the Media Library.